# Helper's function to override `onKeyDown` whenever activity call the function?

Tags: android, onkeydown

I have many `Activity` which need to `override` `onKeyDown` event as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Do something here
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The problem here is that: I have many activities that should call the block of code above (no different in any activity). So I want to write an helper's function like:

```
 public static void overrideOnKeyDownFunction(...);
```

And, in any activity that need to override `onKeyDown` event (same with first code block), I can only call: `Helper.overrideOnKeyDownFunction(...);`!

Can I do some thing like this? And how to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way of sharing that behavior between different activities is making all of them inherit from the same superclass that overrides the onKeyDown method.

So, if you create an Activity with onKeyDown overriden (let's say OverridenBackKeyActivity) any Activity inheriting from OverridenBackKeyActivity will automatically inherit that behavior.

Comment: I think It's a very good idea! However, I still want to have a helper function! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make an activity and extend it in your activities.

```
public class TemplateActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    // Do something here
    return false;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

And then your activities should extend TemplateActivity instead of only Activity.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that:

in Helper class declare your method:

```
public static void overrideOnKeyDownFunction (AnyParamYouNeed param){
    //code here
}
```

And then, in each activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Helper.overrideOnKeyDownFunction(param);
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But again, if you inherit all your activities from a superclass which onKeyDown calls the Helper.overrideOnKeyDownFunction, you only have to write it once.